# WPF Listbox, Multiple rows and columns top align issue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

So what I have is a list box which display 3 images in a row before moving to the next line, this is the code I have used to do it.

```
<ListBox Name="lbListOfItemsOnHDD" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Width="600" Height="450" Margin="5" BorderThickness="0" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="600" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListBox.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu Name="cmLibraryImages" x:Uid="cmLibraryImages">
                            <MenuItem
                                Name="cmCmdDelete"
                                Header="Delete Selected Image"
                                Click="cmCmdDelete_Click" />
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </ListBox.ContextMenu>
                </ListBox>
```

The image widths are always the same so this always displays 3 images before moving the next row, only problem is I'd like the image title below the image, this causes an issue with the top alignment of the pictures not being level (see screenshot below). The images are added at run time using a simple for loop to go through a list that contains the path to the image, image title etc.... The image and text box are added to a stack panel which is then itself added to the listbox.

[image: Unaligned at the top images in WPF list box]

I've tried using the valign top on the various different parts and altering the margins but haven't managed to align them at the top.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

the way to do it a bit more flexible would be to set the ItemTemplate of the ListBox and do it with Binding.
example:

in the code-behind (or better viewmodel if you follow MVVM) you create a class or structure like that:

```
public struct Movie
{
  String Title;
  Uri Source;
}
```

and a ObservableCollection like that:

```
public ObservableCollection<Movie> Movies
{
  get;
  set;
}
```

and you set the Movies collection as ItemsSource of the ListBox (in codebehind or binding)

and finally the XAML

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type typeOfTheAddedItem}">
    <StackPanel Height="500" Orientation="Vertical">
      <Image Source="{Binding Path=PathRelativeTotypeOfTheAddedItem}" />
      <TextBlock="{Binding Path=PathRelativeTotypeOfTheAddedItem}" />
    </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```